# How to find a word between two other words in PHP

Tags: php

I'm just looking for a way to find a string in between two static words.

For example:

It's either

Subbed string-I-want Online

or

Dubbed string-I-want Online

I've tried functions like substr and I can make it so it finds the First space and then prints out the rest of the string.

That would result into the following

string-I-want Online

But I also want to remove Online so it makes it

string-I-want

Preferably a way to find the first space and remove everything before it, and then find the first "Online" and remove everything after it as well as the word "Online". So only the middle part is given out.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions, while not ideal for every task, would work quite well for this:

```
preg_match('/(S|D)ubbed (.*?) Online/', $your_string, $matches);
$text = $matches[2];
```